# Rewrite rule not applying

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm really struggling getting to match this URL my htaccess rule and nothing I try seems to work.

This is the url I want to match

http://www.xyz.com/events/my-event-in-town/

```
RewriteRule ^my-event-in-([^/]+)/$ /new-url/$1/ [R=301]
```

Hope someone can point out my obvious mistake

I also need to remove the first /events/ part from the URL

Comment: Try removing the first `^`. Or is `my-event-in-town` your document root?

Comment: That works except I need to remove the "events" part also? I though the ^ meant start matching from here?

Comment: As @servant wrote in his answer `^` is start of line rather than start match here. Also `$` is end of line. You should not have to do anything on the `events` part unless you want to confirm it's really in there. Bur servant answered it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
RewriteRule ^events/my-event-in-([^/]+)/$ /new-url/$1/ [R=301]
```

Or:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/events/
RewriteRule my-event-in-([^/]+)/$ /new-url/$1/ [R=301]
```

Your rule will only match to *http://www.xyz.com/my-event-in-town/* because the `^` meant the start of line anchor.

Comment: Thank you for that, that worked. By start of line, do you mean everything after the domain name?

Comment: @jhodgson4 Yes, everything after the domain name. But maybe it could be everything after the containing directory of the _.htaccess_ file _(but I'm not sure about it)_.